# Bootstrap Navbar Fixed top on OverFlow Horizontal set fixed height make content Scrollable to avoid toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I avoid use of Toggle button navigation of Bootstrap 
and add on OverFlow Horizontal set fixed height a horizontal scroll with hidden bar for movil...

scheme code:

```
                <div class="row border-bottom">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top white-bg" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
                            <a class="logo-lrg" href="#"> <img alt="image" class="img-circle1" src="sources/img/logos/LOGO.png" /></a>
                        </div>
    <!--START MENU NEED HORIZONTAL SCROLL-->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                            <li> <a id="" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Mesa de Control</a> </li>
                            <li id="" class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><span class="tx1">Administración</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                    <li><a id="" href="#">Aprobaciones</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="" href="#">Manejo de Productos</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="" href="#">Control Días Venta Hábiles</a></li>
                                </ul>           
                            </li>
                            <li class="logout-click"> <a id="pro-save-p-gen-logout" href="#" > <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <span class="tx1">Cerrar</span> </a> </li>
                        </ul>
<!--END MENU NEED HORIZONTAL SCROLL-->
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

So far it looks like this:

[image]

**Update**

this is a example that I want but not work with dropdown on tabs.

http://www.codeply.com/go/DclUsokAoV

Comment: do you mean you need a fixed width container?

Comment: yes, but need add the scroll option to slide in movil.

Comment: @reenleedr Scroll slide: fixed height, i mean that user can use the finger to slide or scroll content to right or left like you scroll app on application menu  of android

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `dropdown-menu-right` instead of `pull-right` along with `dropdown-menu`